# Feature Folder Path Name Doubled

Tags: visual-studio, feature

Why when I create a new feature in VS2010 and deploy it, I see the Features folder has my solution but the name is "Doubled Up".  Is this expected behavior?  See my sample below:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\WEC.SPS.Feature.DisableNewFolder_WEC.SPS.Feature.DisableNewFolder`

Answer (score 2):

ok, the nomenclature for this is:

FeatureManifests

```
FeatureManifest Location="ProjectName_FeatureName\Feature.xml"
```

FeatureManifests

So here is what I did:

1. Double clicked on my feature to open the feature properties. Searched for the Deployment Path property
2. Deployment Path = $SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$

Replaced it with:

Deployment Path = $SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$

Regards,
Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

No, I have not come across this - could it be that you have a namespace in your solution that is the same as your project/solution name or your web name? Check that you havent duplicated the name in your solution somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the Assembly and Namespace are the same. Other than that, its a typical C# project in VS2010. The manifest looks like this:   <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="WEC.SPS.Feature.DisableNewFolderB_WEC.SPS.Feature.DisableNewFolderB\Feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. You should be able to change the default feature name in the feature properties window in Visual Studio.